# Javascript object within object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a few issues with creating an object within an object, it's syntax related but can't seem to remember how I can achieve this.

```
ajaxRequest = {
that: null,
request: null,  
multiRun: null,
multiRunTimer: null,
defaults={
    ext: '',
    url: '',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    payload: null,
    beforeSend: 'handleBefore',
    error: 'handleError',
    complete: 'handleCompletion',
    pass: false,
    debug: false,
    multiRunBlock: false                
}}
```

I get a syntax error of Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Comment: Have a look how you assign values to the other properties.

Comment: use ":" instead of "=" in the code after "defaults"

Comment: When you're within an object, assign properties using a colon (`:`) instead of an `=`.

Comment: Use jslint or something that uses it, like jsfiddle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `:` to separate 'properties' from their respective values:

```
defaults: {
    ext: '',
    url: '',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    payload: null,
    beforeSend: 'handleBefore',
    error: 'handleError',
    complete: 'handleCompletion',
    pass: false,
    debug: false,
    multiRunBlock: false                
}}
```

Some reading:

- http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php

Answer (score 2):

You need a `:` instead of `=` for defaults.

```
var ajaxRequest = {
that: null,
request: null,  
multiRun: null,
multiRunTimer: null,
defaults: {
    ext: '',
    url: '',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    payload: null,
    beforeSend: 'handleBefore',
    error: 'handleError',
    complete: 'handleCompletion',
    pass: false,
    debug: false,
    multiRunBlock: false                
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ajaxRequest = {
that: null,
request: null,  
multiRun: null,
multiRunTimer: null,
defaults: {
    ext: '',
    url: '',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    payload: null,
    beforeSend: 'handleBefore',
    error: 'handleError',
    complete: 'handleCompletion',
    pass: false,
    debug: false,
    multiRunBlock: false                
}}
```

As it says, you have an issue with the `=`. User `=` to assign a variable, but properties within an object should use `:` (just like the rest of your properties)